# How to replace `until.. sleep` with `inotifywait` on a specific created file?

Tags: linux, shell, inotify

I have code like this to trigger a script in [/etc/inittab](https://github.com/Webconverger/webc/blob/master/etc/inittab#L61):

```
until test -p /tmp/updates.pipe
do
    sleep 0.25
done
```

Which I want to refactor since the `sleep` floods debug logs, when debugging with `set -x`.

IIUC `inotifywait` only watches on directories.

```
inotifywait -e create /tmp
```

So how do I make it only proceed after seeing the CREATE event of the **/tmp/updates.pipe** file, and not any other file in `/tmp`?

Comment: https://github.com/Webconverger/webc/commit/ae1cc1dc73e16d0f341cd12b0585900efc0fa4cf

Answer (score 1):

the quiet flag to grep causes it to break out as soon as it sees a match. The following should work under bash.

grep -q updates.pipe <(inotifywait -e create -m /tmp)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
while read OUTPUT
do
    if echo $OUTPUT | grep -q "CREATE updates.pipe"; then break; fi
done < <(inotifywait -qm -e create /tmp)
```

This doesn't work with all shells, though.

Here is another solution which should work with all shells:

```
inotifywait -qm -e create /tmp | while read OUTPUT
do
    if echo $OUTPUT | grep -q "CREATE updates.pipe"; then break; fi
done
```

But for some mysterious reasons it only breaks after the next output after `CREATE updates.pipe`, does anybody know why?

Comment: @hendry I don't know if there is a nice solution without spawning a subshell.

Comment: Oh, the second block of code works without the "second occurrence" bug. Nice! Not sure if there is any point now keeping the non-working first block?

Comment: @hendry The first version should work on all shells, I just don't know why it does not break immediately.

Comment: well, it don't want to accept an answer with that first block since the fact it doesn't break immediately is a bit of deal breaker imo

Comment: I switched the two solutions. You might still wait for a better solution if there is any.

Comment: You can work around the "next output" problem by using a named pipe, like my commit here: https://github.com/Webconverger/webc/blob/1853c43432b9b9aafd4c42847d6f995b7eecb6db/etc/webc/webc.conf#L67